# преобразование и отображение char в с++

Tags: c++

есть проблема, ввожу русские буквы, например "у", по идее оно должно отображать в формате char "у" , а в формате int номер по таблице ASCII "227", но оно отображает "г" и "-29", хотя с латиницей и знаками препинания работает корректно. Почему так, и что с эти делать?

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
char x;
int y;
cout << "Введите символ _";
cin >> x;
y = x;
cout << x << "   ";
cout << y << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если отображает -29 - это означает, что у вас signed char, а значит максимально возможное число это 127 (если не ошибаюсь). Вам следует как минимум использовать unsigned char

Comment: к тому же где вы нашли в стандартном аски русские буквы?

Comment: Заработало спасибо, unsigned char помогло, плюс удалил setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); все встало на свои места